# com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/internal/Utility$GraphMeRequestWithCacheCallback;

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use facebook SDK, then I import facebook module to my project, but this problem will appear:

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/facebook/internal/Utility$GraphMeRequestWithCacheCallback;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Comment: remove unused libraries from libs folder

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[22,23)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
}

Comment: ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=19
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23.0.0
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=23

Comment: @user3349474 Edit main post!!

Comment: Solve it is just remove unused libraries.Thank for all

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code to your gradle file in android block :

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

And it is also possible that your parse dependancy and facebook module both have same jar file in it.

Check if there is any common jar that they both uses. And if It is true then
remove same jar from any of both dependencies like below :

```
compile('your module name') {
      exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

Hope It will help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse then, this result would be obvious in ending dex error.

If not try adding Dex library jar and enable multidex true in application gradle file.